# How to use character array password for jtds connection

Tags: java, sql-server, security, t-sql, jtds

Using the jtds driver for java, how do I connect to sql server database using a character array as the password (for security reasons instead of a string). So far, I can only connection if the password is a string not a character array. Thanks

Comment: Can you create a loop to go through the character array, and using a String variable and append each character from the character array to the end of the String, and then use that String as the password?

Comment: what is the advantage of that over the toString() method. Thanks

Comment: Well you have me there, it's just a longer route to get to the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you cannot...

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/doc/net/sourceforge/jtds/jdbc/Driver.html

However, I wouldn't worry about this too much... Are you running untrusted code in the same JVM?

Yes it is a best practice, however, there are likely "bigger fish to fry" in terms of security.

Comment: No I am just using the active directory password so I just want to make things as secure as possible. How secure is it using a string as the password? I am a novice with security so I want to make sure I am being honest with my boss about security since it is the medical profession and security is very important. Thanks

Comment: You'll be fine fine, this is the least of your worries... If you're concerned about security, hire an expert to come audit your system.

Comment: btw I am collecting the password from a JPasswordField. Thanks again for all the help.